# Regular expression in java, shared symbols

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to remove from string all words shorter than 3 symbols. I have following code

```
String s = "a abc ab ab ab abc ab";
s = s.replaceAll("(^|\\s)([a-z]{1,2})(\\s|$)", "$1$3");
```

I run it, but output is

```
 abc  ab  abc
```

I suppose problem exists because 3 words " ab ab ab " share same whitespaces and thats why second "ab" is not entry of regex. How can I make it work properly?

Comment: Does it work for you to use word boundaries rather than explicit start, end and spaces? [`\b\w{1,2}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/bK6wU2/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` instead and delete all words that are too short:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\b[a-z]{1,2}\\b", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
string.replaceAll("\\s[a-z]{1,2}(?=\\s|$)|^[a-z]{1,2}\\s", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bK6wU2/6)

- `\\s[a-z]{1,2}(?=\\s|$)` matches one or two letter words along with the preceding space character.
- `^[a-z]{1,2}\\s` matches one or two letter words present at the start along with the following space.
- Replacing the matched chars with empty string will give you the desired output.